# How can I set multiple path for 1 page in NextJS pages directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a project with 2 different themes. And I can switch themes with environment. Its all works perfectly but for paths, some pages should open same page with different paths. For example ;

For open contact page i normally using /contact path.

But if I switch theme from environment and restart project, /contact page shouldn't work and instead of /contact, I want to use /iletisim path for open exact same page.
And my some of pages is like /contact/[...contact-detail-item]. How can i handle it too ?
Thanks for all helps!

Versions: NextJS 13 Pages Directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why some page should be reached by more than one path. Pages and paths have a "one-to-one" relation, and you are writing doubled code at your backend if two routes "open the exact same page", as you wrote.

Also, change "themes" like light/dark are frontend issues; the data your server provided when queried for the "/contacts" path is not theme-dependable.

If the answer didn't help, please add more details about your problem

Comment: Thanks for response. I wrote theme but actually its 2 different project. We have 2 project with same UI. One is for polish one is for czech. So there is different languages. I handle static strings with i18 but for path names, idk how can i handle it.  In polish it should open /contact-but-polish but in czech it should open /contact-but-czech

Comment: In most of documents, they writing you should handle /pl/pathName - /cz/pathName but I can't use this. pathNames should locale name. And there shouldn't /cz/-/pl/ prefix before path.

Comment: If you are buildind an API that return data to a site, you query your database for that contact, no matter the UI language. You could setup a path "/contact/contactID/PL" or "/contact/contactID&language=PL" (contactID beeing a variable, not a word from the path). Let the front handle the UI. But It's still not clear to me what's the difference between the two pages. "/contact-but-polish" and "/contact-but-czech" have the same visual apparence, but they display two different people? When you said "two projects", you mean "two databases"?

Comment: Yes they has two different databases. And there a system for get metadatas from backend for every url in database. So in first database, when i request /contact to it, it sending me metadatas for it. If its not found, it shows 404 page in frontend. But in other database, there is not /contact path in it. Instead of /contact , there is response with /contact-but-pl request. So they want paths with locale languages. But in project, its already same component for both paths.